# Codeigniter Active record SQL injection

Tags: codeigniter, sql-injection

Is below query vulnerable to SQL Injection where $evilInput is from get/post request.

```
$this->db->select($evilInput); 
$this->db->where($evilInput2 ,"abc"); 
$query =  $this->db->get($evilInput3);
$count = $query->num_rows();
```

and

```
$this->db->where("a=$evilInput");
```

Comment: are you asking if it is as good as using binds or are you asking if the functions escape the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to point out that all these are vulnerable to SQL injection on a default installation of CodeIgniter. The following results have been tested and verified.

**1)** `$this->db->select($evilInput)`

Here the input goes after the `select` keyword.

```
select evilInput from table_name where column_name = 1;
```

Here, if my evil input parameter contains something like:

`updatexml(null,concat(0x3a,version()),null)-- -`

The actual query will become:

`select updatexml(null,concat(0x3a,version()),null)-- - from table_name where column_name = 1;`

**2)** `$this->db->where($evilInput ,"abc")`

Here the input goes to the column name after `WHERE` clause.

`select * from table_name where evilInput = 1;`

CodeIgniter will not escape or filter this input. This can be easily exploited with something like:

`1=1 and updatexml(null,concat(0x3a,version()),null)-- -`

**3)** $query =  $this->db->get($evilInput3)

Here the input goes in the table name.

`select * from evilInput where column_name = 1;`

CodeIgniter won't prevent SQL Injection if the user input is something like:

`information_schema.tables where 1=1 and updatexml(null,concat(0x3a,version()),null)-- -`

**4)** $this->db->where("a=$evilInput")

This is vulnerable to simple SQL Injection because the input is directly concatenated to the SQL query.